# Modifying the cache access delay in gem5 does not work

Tags: caching, cpu-cache, gem5

When testing the cache access latency on my gem5, the access latency of l1 is 100 cycles lower than that of l2.  My modification is to modify the `tag_latency, data_latency, and response_latency` in the `L2 class` in `gem5/configs/common/Caches.py`. Their original value was 20. I changed them all to 5 or all to 0. Every time I **recompile gem5**, when I run it again, the time does not change. Why is that?

I am using classical cache

By the way, does the meaning of data_latency, tag_latency and response_latency mean data access delay, tag delay, and delay in responsing to CPU  ?

> gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt --debug-flags=O3CPUAll    --debug-start=120000000000
> --outdir=gem5/results/test/final    gem5/configs/example/attack_code_config.py
> --cmd=final
> --benchmark_stdout=gem5/results/test/final/final.out
> --benchmark_stderr=gem5/results/test/final/final.err
> --mem-size=4GB --l1d_size=32kB --l1d_assoc=8 --l1i_size=32kB --l1i_assoc=8
> --l2_size=256kB --l2_assoc=8 --l1d_replacement=LRU --l1i_replacement=LRU
> --caches --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU

`--cmd` `--l1d_replacement` etc. are the options I added to the
option.

Comment: What is the command line you are running?

Comment: thank you. I added to the question

Comment: Could you reduce your command line to a minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I just checked it , because I mistakenly thought that l2cache is the same as l1cache. It only needs to be initialized by defining parameters. I later found out that I need to use --l2cache, otherwise there is no l2cache. Now changing the parameters has an effect. thank you. you are a really nice person.

Comment: Glad you found the solution.  Passing command line arguments is practical, but is more error prone in the long run. I recommend that you create your own files with your desired default configuration (like the ones of O3_ARM_v7a_3) so that errors like these are less likely to happen.

Comment: Hello, Daniel Carvalho. Do you know how to use write-through cache in gem5? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65640561/how-to-set-the-cache-to-use-write-through-policy-in-gem5